# UWP Runtime Component - Using Images

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-runtime

It seems that using images in a Universal Windows Component is impossible...

I have some images in the `Assets` Folder

[image: Assets]

Each has a build type of Content.

Now when I try to use it XAML via the image element:
`<Image Source="Assets/signal-strength-1.png" />` nothing shows up in the designer.

I've done plenty of WPF work but new to UWP. There are some obvious differences but I can't seem to figure this out. Any ideas? I really need to get the design view to work better. I hate having to hit play every time I need to play with the layout.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try <Image Source="/Assets/signal-strength-1.png" /> this? One more / before starting of path

Comment: @GaurangDave Yes...to no avail.

Answer (score 2):

Nevermind...figured it out: `ms-appx:\\\<component-name>\Assets\signal-strength-1.png />`